# [WebdriverIO][Typescript] Is it possible to get a custom variable from the browser window?

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

Hi lets assume i have a custom variable in the browser.["Custom variable"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x51KZ.png) Is it possible to get it with webdriverIO with the browser.execute() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with js.

```
browser.execute("return a")
```

Here is the sample I tried in python using js which is equivalent to  browser.execute.
[image]